# Seleccionar elementos duplicados agregados a mi base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Cometí un error insertando registros de forma masiva en mi base de datos y muchos elementos fueron duplicados. Sucede que los elementos que ya están dentro de la base de datos muchos de ellos esta relacionados con otros elementos de otra tabla, por lo que esos elementos no los puedo modificar o borrar ya que perderían esa relación.

Estoy buscando los elementos repetidos con la siguiente consulta sql:

```
SELECT telefono FROM clientes
GROUP BY telefono
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Esto me trae todos los elementos duplicados, eso esta bien. El problema es que me trae todos los elementos que ya estaban dentro de la base de datos y no los que fueron agregados recientemente.

Me pueden ayudar diciéndome de que forma puedo traer los elementos duplicados pero que fueron los últimos que agregue filtrandolos por la fecha de creación o por el ID?

Comment: Intenta entonces filtrando por fecha para poder obtener los recientes. Por ejemplo buscando los registros desde el dia en que se duplicaron para aca. Eso claro si tienes un campo de fecha...

Comment: @Einer tienes toda la razón. Que tonto me siento.

Comment: ¿Y como se sabe cuando una fila es reciente o no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta entonces filtrando por fecha para poder obtener los recientes. Por ejemplo buscando los registros desde el dia en que se duplicaron para aca. Por ejemplo:

```
select * from telefonos where fecha_registro between '12/01/2021 00:00:000' and getdate()
```

Eso claro si tienes un campo de fecha.

Answer (score 1):

Es fácil encontrar duplicados con un campo:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

Entonces, si tenemos una tabla:

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@asd.com
2    Sam    asd@asd.com
3    Tom    asd@asd.com
4    Bob    bob@asd.com
5    Tom    asd@asd.com
```

Esta consulta nos dará John, Sam, Tom, Tom porque todos tienen lo mismo email.

Sin embargo, lo que quiero es obtener duplicados con el mismo email y name .

Es decir, quiero obtener "Tom", "Tom".

La razón por la que necesito esto: cometí un error y permití insertar duplicados namey emailvalores. Ahora necesito eliminar / cambiar los duplicados, así que primero necesito encontrarlos.